# How do I completely uninstall a custom entity implemented by my module?

Tags: 7, entities, installation

I need to write an uninstall use-case for my custom entity. I just want to know what operations I should take care of, in order to completely uninstall my entity/module and all attached fields (including custom fields created by Field API).

Should I use `hook_uninstall` and how should I implement this hook?

Answer (score 2):

The tables declared by the [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) will be automatically remove when you uninstall your module.

If you need to remove other tables or variables use the [hook_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7)

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of [function field_attach_delete_bundle](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_delete_bundle/7) would be a better approache here.